# Need to clic twice to get language to change

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, cookies

I am developing a simple landing page where you can choose the language of the text displayed.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$defaultLang = isset($_COOKIE['lang_bcn']) ? $_COOKIE['lang_bcn'] : 'es'; //default 
if(isset($_GET['selectedLanguage'])){
    $languageOption = "";
    switch($_GET['selectedLanguage']){
        case 'en':
        $languageOption = 'en';
        break;
        case 'es':
        $languageOption = 'es';
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    if(isset($languageOption)){
        setcookie('lang_bcn',$languageOption,time()+24*7*60*60);//set cookie to expire in 7 days
    }
}

$arrayLang['en']['subtitle'] = 'Discover and learn by playing';
$arrayLang['es']['subtitle'] = 'Descubre y aprende jugando';
?>

//links to language selection
     <a href="?selectedLanguage=es">ES</a>
     <a href="?selectedLanguage=en">EN</a>

//showing the text in the selected language
      <p><?php echo $arrayLang[$defaultLang]['subtitle'];?></p>
```

And it works great, except that to change the language I have to click twice on the chosen language link. With just one click the language of the text doesn't change and I can't find the reason why.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$defaultLang` variable is defined on the top and it depends on the cookies. When you click your button the first time, the cookies aren't set yet, so `$defaultLang` is going to be `'es'` and after that you set the cookies. The second time you click your button cookies are already set, so `$defaultLang` variable is set to proper value. Just put it below `if` statement and it should work.

```
if(isset($_GET['selectedLanguage'])){
    $languageOption = "";
    switch($_GET['selectedLanguage']){
        case 'en':
        $languageOption = 'en';
        break;
        case 'es':
        $languageOption = 'es';
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    if(isset($languageOption)){
        setcookie('lang_bcn',$languageOption,time()+24*7*60*60);//set cookie to expire in 7 days
    }
}

$defaultLang = isset($_COOKIE['lang_bcn']) ? $_COOKIE['lang_bcn'] : 'es'; //default
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! Your code makes a lot of sense but it does not change the situation (even after deleting cookies) :((

Comment: this line was the problem: $defaultLang = isset($_COOKIE['lang_bcn']) ? $_COOKIE['lang_bcn'] : 'es'; //default .. Thanks again!!